# state transition falling edge

Tags: vhdl, state-machine

I am revisiting VHDL after many years.  I am trying to setup a basic state machine with a counter trigger at some overflow period.

For some reason I am getting state transitions on the falling edge of the m_tick clock.  There should only be a transition on the rising edge based on the m_tick <= '1' in the state process?  I must be overlooking something.

I am testing in isim.  I am sure I'm probably doing some not very smart.

Thanks.

```
entity nes_ctl is
generic(
        N: integer :=  3;       --17 bit overflow 131k
 );
port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        n_reset : in std_logic
);
end nes_ctl;

architecture Behavioral of nes_ctl is

signal count_reg, count_next: unsigned(N-1 downto 0);   --counter to produce tick
signal m_tick: std_logic;
--state variable
type state_type is (s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5);
signal state_reg, state_next: state_type;
signal reset: std_logic;    --inverted reset signal

begin

reset <= not(n_reset);  --invert the reset signal

--syncronos logic
process(clk)
begin
    if(reset= '1') then
        count_reg <= (others=>'0');
        state_reg <= s0;
    elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
        count_reg <= count_next;
        state_reg <= state_next;
    end if;
end process;

count_next <= count_reg +1;     --increment counter, will overflow
m_tick <= '1' when count_reg = 0 else '0';      -- tick on every overflow

--STATE MACHINE
process(m_tick)
begin
    if(m_tick <= '1') then  --only when m_tick goes high
        case state_reg is
            when s0 =>
                state_next <= s1;
            when s1 =>
                state_next <= s2;
            when s2 =>
                state_next <= s3;
            when s3 =>
                state_next<= s4;
            when s4 =>
                state_next<= s5;
            when s5 =>
                state_next <= s0;
        end case;   
    else 
        state_next <= state_reg; --keep same state.  no       latches.
    end if;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```

Comment: What does a relational operator `<=` do on std_logic? If you want to detect a rising edge, `if rising_edge(m_tick)` would be the obvious way

Comment: Good point.  should have been if (m_tick = '1').

Comment: My logic was that m_tick triggered the process, so there was an edge on m_tick.  The if(m_tick = '1') is the check to see if it was the rising edge.  What is the defacto standard for such as check?  rising_edge(m_tick) like you sugges?

Comment: I changed the original code to m_tick='1' rather m_tick<='1' and the simulation ran fine.  But, I think you guys made some good points that pointed out that this is a gated clock implementation?  Which is bad practice?   Sorry trying adjust my thinking from embedded processing.  OUCH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

m_tick <= '1' will be true any time m_tick is low, not just the rising edge.  If you intend to use m_tick as a clock, you need to use m_tick'event and m_tick='1', as you do for clk.  If instead you intend the rising edge of m_tick to be a clock enable signal, you need to clock your process with the clk signal and detect the rising edge of m_tick by comparing it with a delayed version:

```
process(clk)
begin
    if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
        m_tick_q <= m_tick;

        -- only when m_tick goes high
        if m_tick='1' and m_tick_q='0' then
            case state_reg is
            ...
```

Comment: " m_tick <= '1' will be true any time m_tick is low, not just the rising edge ".  Can you explain why m_tick will be true even when low?  What method would you recommend where I am trying to run the state machine at a slower rate than the clock?

Comment: Actually, since m_tick presumably can be 0 or 1, your m_tick <= 1 is always true, and in simulations your process runs anytime m_tick changes.  In actual hardware, however, this would not be the case, and the process would run continuously (ie: asynchronous logic).

If you want to run the state machine slower than the main clock, I provided an example in the code above.  The process is synchronous to the clk signal, and the "case state_reg" code only runs when m_tick transitions from low to high.